# Saving a list of tuples in .mat format

Tags: python, mat

I'd like to save a list of tuples geenrated in python as a .mat file for importing in MATLAB. Since I couldn't directly use `savemat('file.mat',tuplist)` ,I converted the list of tuples to a dataframe.Here is my sample code,

```
import mat4py
import scipy.io as io
import pandas as pd
import pprint as pprint

tuplist=[(0, 1,0), (0, 1,1), (0, 1,2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(tuplist)
print(df)
io.savemat('file.mat',df)
```

I get the following error,
`TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

Any suggestions on how to solve this error?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CreateGraph.py", line 27, in <module>
    io.savemat('Edges',df)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 219, in savemat
    MW.put_variables(mdict)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 832, in put_variables
    if name[0] == '_':
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Edit:

From the comment posted below, I understand, I have made a mistake by passing a dataframe instead of a dictionary in the `savemat` command. I'd like to ask for suggestion on alternative ways of converting the list of tuples to a .mat format.

Comment: Please post the full error stack, as always

Comment: @user8408080 I have updated the post.Please have a  look

Comment: The documentation for `savemat` says to pass a dictionary. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html#scipy.io.savemat

Comment: @RuthC Thanks a lot for pointing my mistake. Since, the list of tuples that I've is not a key-value pair I am not sure how to convert this to a dictionary

Comment: Just start a try with `{0:(0, 1, 0), 1:(0, 1, 1),...}` and see how it goes

Comment: @user8408080 The list of tuples is the output of another function in my actual code.I'm afraid that can't be modified manually

Comment: Of course it can: `my_test_dict = {i:element for i, element in enumerate(list_of_tuples)}`

Comment: @user8408080 Thanks for the tip. However, the same error occurs even after replacing `io.savemat('file.mat',df)` with `io.savemat('file.mat',my_test_dict)`

Comment: I think it expects the dictionary keys to be strings, so maybe try `my_test_dict = {“myvar{}”.format(i) : element for i, element in enumerate(list_of_tuples)}`

Comment: @RuthC Thanks a lot ,it helped me in resolving the error